# Distributed md5 crack software?

Tags: cryptography, md5

I'm studying about cracking password using brute force, and in my way I found softwares like John the  Ripper and MDCrack, that works really nice, but are restricted to one machine.

There is some software that I can install on my LAN PCs, and distribute the work of cracking the password? OR some software that allow use that mentioned softwares in a distributed way?

Comment: a commercial tool: http://www.elcomsoft.com/edpr.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[John the Ripper supports parallelization.](http://openwall.info/wiki/john/parallelization) This uses OpenMP or MPI. All of this is open source.

Answer (score 1):

[ELCOMSOFT](http://www.elcomsoft.com/edpr.html) is another option, but it's not free.